# PHP curl returns empty string sometimes and no error

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to call a site that returns a json result. It works fine somedays but other days it returns an empty string and no error.

Here is my code

```
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array(
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0',
    'Accept: application/json',
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.bovada.lv/services/sports/event/v2/events/A/description/football/nfl");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$contents=curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($contents, true);
print_r($json);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Any idea why it would work some days but not others? Also, if I use firefox or postman it works every single time.

Here is the verbose output, Content-Length is 0

```
*   Trying 157.185.178.148:443...
* Connected to www.bovada.lv (157.185.178.148) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: c:\php\cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=www.bovada.lv
*  start date: Jan  5 01:30:09 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Feb  6 01:30:08 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.bovada.lv" matched cert's "www.bovada.lv"
*  issuer: C=BE; O=GlobalSign nv-sa; CN=GlobalSign GCC R3 DV TLS CA 2020
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x1e88f349bf0)
> GET /services/sports/event/v2/events/A/description/football/nfl HTTP/2
Host: www.bovada.lv
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0
accept: application/json

* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< date: Tue, 12 Sep 2023 16:22:57 GMT
< content-length: 0
< x-varnish: 325065529
< set-cookie: TS01ed9118=014b5d5d07f3386e1d6b4faa70e50ad6021f9eccb5336e851c55d0c1bf5a020540f29b463d4d69b3f109a2c2206f136d64e4531720; Path=/; Domain=.www.bovada.lv
< age: 1535
< via: 1.1 PS-YUL-01c3G98:1 (W), 1.1 PS-YUL-01Ge696:2 (W), 1.1 hx172:6 (W), 1.1 ls25:5 (W)
< x-px: ht ls25DFW
< x-ws-request-id: 65009061_ls25_19321-37062
< strict-transport-security: max-age=16070400
< server: PWS/8.3.1.0.8
< cache-control: max-age=604800
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.bovada.lv left intact
```

Here's the response from Firefox, Content-Length is 112293
[image]

Comment: If it's returning an empty response with no error, that's a problem at the server end, not a problem with your script. Other than contacting the service operator, there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @ADyson it helps, I updated my post with the verbose output....still doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @Barmar I would accept that logic if it also returned an empty string in a browser or postman, but it never does

Comment: Maybe you're running into a rate limit.

Comment: You've got a 200 status and a content length of 0. That's not an error, that's the server telling you that there's no data.

Comment: Is your Postman request absolutely identical to this one? Did you use Postman to generate the PHP cURL code you've shown us? It can do this automatically.

Comment: @AlexHowansky if you paste the link in the browser, there's always data

Comment: Nope. wget, curl, php, Chrome, Firefox all return status 200 and 0 bytes.

Comment: Updated the post with my response headers using Firefox...Content-Length is 112293

Comment: It's a server-side issue, pretty clearly different for us. Maybe spoof your User-Agent to mimic Firefox?

Comment: I see an `x-varnish` header in my output that I don't in yours. Maybe I'm getting a cached empty page, and you're not.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Just tack a `?<random number>` to the end of the URL to bust the cache.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I think you nailed it

Comment: Still a server-side issue of course, as they're caching an erroneously generated empty page -- but at least now you can work around it.